# Forcing Column Headings in SSRS Chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I'm struggling with charting some data in SSRS with a column chart. The data in my SQL select returns a number of devices and their battery level as a decimal e.g

```
Device 1, 90%
Device 2, 90%
Device 3, 80%
Device 4, 30%
```

I have rounded the real battery percentage so the view can only ever output, 100 to 0 in 10% chunks.

I then have a column chart in SSRS which counts the number of devices which fall into each 10% and charts them. The issue is that in this example only the columns for 30%, 80% and 90% appear, along with their headings. What I would like is to show all of the titles from 0 to 100 but only draw a column in where there is a record.

I've tried forcing the scale with 10 increments but that doesn't help. I guess this question is two fold. Is there a way that I can force SSRS to display the column headers even though there is no data for those specific headers? Any other way that this can be achieved if not?

I have a feeling that I might need to do something in the select to force the data to include these but not sure how I might do that.

Here is an example of the chart currently:

[image: Chart Example]

As you can see, I only get column titles for 30, 80 and 90.

Comment: is it possible to support your question with visual  chart/graph?

Comment: Sorry yes, good idea. I have just updated the question with an example.

Comment: Looks like i've fixed it. I had to add a temporary table to do it